# find total of column category and insert total into another table column

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to have SQL find the total number of apples in the column "fruits" from Table A, and insert that count total into a column 
("total fruits") in Table B but cant get the wording right.

This statement returns 10,

```
SELECT COUNT ("fruits") 
FROM grocery_list  
WHERE "fruits" = ('Apples');
```

but don't know how to move the result to a column in table B?

Comment: You need to show sample data from `B` to explain what you mean by "move the result to a column".

Comment: Table B has a column with a list of fruits. The next column over (fruit_total) is where I need the total count from table A.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want an `update` or `insert`.  I might speculate:

```
update b
    set cnt = (select count(*) from grocery_list where fruits = 'Apples')
    where . . .;
```

The `where` condition specifies which row should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try blow for insert:

```
INSERT INTO B SET "total fruits" = SELECT COUNT ("fruits") FROM grocery_list WHERE "fruits" = ('Apples');
```

For Update :

```
UPDATE B SET "total fruits" = SELECT COUNT ("fruits") FROM grocery_list WHERE "fruits" = ('Apples');
```